# Hybridisation and bond strength

Tags: hybridization, valence-bond-theory

I'm a high school student with minimal mathematical knowledge about the theory of chemical bond. (I just have a bit of theoretical background). I came across a statement which stated that "The more is the s character in a hybrid orbital, the stronger will be the bond. "
I also came across a statement the "The extent of overlap increases with increase in directionality of bond." (Example : p-p > s-p > s-s reflects the order of the extent of overlap of orbitals keeping the internuclear distance same). What I think is that the more will be the overlap , the stronger will be the bond formed. How can I account for these contradictory statements? I'm confused. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE. Feel free to take the short [tour] or visit the [help] if you have any questions about how this site works. Best of luck with your question!

Comment: The statements are not contradictory when read both carefully. One is about overlapping and other is about strength. Also, you might be getting confused that more overlap leads to more strong bond but the actual statement is for a particular type orbital(s, p, d, etc.) greater extent of overlapping leads to more strong bond.

Comment: Thanks shubham for your consideration. So should I conclude that the second statement is only valid for pure atomic orbitals in reference to their bond strength?